# MD5 hash in Rust

Tags: rust, md5

I'm trying to create an md5-hash from a string in Rust.

This is what I have been able to find in the documentation:

```rust
let digest = md5::compute(b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

assert_eq!(format!("{:x}", digest), "c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b");
```

**So now my code is:**

```
fn main(){
    let digest = md5::compute(b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    assert_eq!(format!("{:x}", digest), "c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b");
}
```

I can't figure out how to import the md5 lib, so I am getting this error message:

```
use of undeclared type or module `md5`
```

Comment: Please consider revisiting The Rust Programming Language book, especially [Chapter 7, section 4, on Using external packages](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#using-external-packages).

Answer (score 5):

You should add `use md5` import at the top of your file:

```
use md5;

fn main(){
    let digest = md5::compute(b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    assert_eq!(format!("{:x}", digest), "c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=033930be4a8d3c881af0bf1914643194)

Comment: That only works in the playground, on an actual project using cargo, you'd add a md5 = "..." to the dependencies in your Cargo.toml

Comment: View the repo for md5 (i like [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/md5)), use the copy button to grab the lib and version and add this to the `[dependencies]` section of your `Cargo.toml` file like the previous poster mentioned